# Determine Where Values Are Added to Render Array in Drupal 7

Tags: theming

I am trying to determine where specific values are being added to the render array.  I am chasing down a bug that hides HTML when a particular module is installed and adds back that HTML when a second module is installed.

I am using NetBeans and XDebug and setting breakpoints at various drupal_render lines but there are so many and I am not sure if setting the breakpoint at the drupal_render declaration in common.inc is helping.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: using break points in core files isn't going to help you. what two modules? what is the array (node, form, variable, etc)? what is being removed?